# Table Data not in HTML

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to use Selenium to use data populated from what I assume is an SQL query behind the scenes.  I fill out a small form, and it generates a table with the information.

However, when I look at the HTML or use Shift+Ctrl+C to view the HTML, I do not see the data anywhere.

For example, looking at a particular cell in the table, if I inspect the element what I see is...

```
<div class="cll" role="gridcell" style="width: 146px; cursor: auto; display: inline-block;" cidx="0" cst="1"><input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="text" name="x_" 901="" id="proj_" class="abcd" readonly="" tabindex="-1" size="33" maxlength="25" style="width: 142px;"><span align="top" title="Show text entry popup" class="tExpandoBtn" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></span></div>
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="text" name="x_" 901="" id="proj_" class="abcd" readonly="" tabindex="-1" size="33" maxlength="25" style="width: 142px;">
```

However, none of that contains the information in the cell which is some arbitrary name of a project.  Is a scenario like this impossible to get the actual value "PROJECTNAME" out of the cell that I expect?

Comment: When you use developer tools to look at the DOM, do you see the contents in there? That's more reliable than view source.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data table is being populated by AJAX after the page loads. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard combo does a "view source" which gives you the HTML document as it was initially delivered to the browser before JavaScript modified the page.

Right-click in the browser window and choose "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" to see the document object model as it currently is, not as of being delivered to the browser.